# Updating NextJS/playwrights nodejs version?

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, playwright

My build on Vercel has started failing due to Playwright's depreciated Node.js version:

> Error: Node.js version 12.x is deprecated. Deployments created on or
> after 2022-08-09 will fail to build. Please set Node.js Version to
> 16.x in your Project Settings to use Node.js 16. This change is the result of a decision made by an upstream infrastructure provider
> (AWS).

Followed by:

> error playwright@1.22.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this
> module. Expected version ">=14". Got "12.22.9" error Found
> incompatible module.

Is there a way to update Playwright's built in Node.js version?

Comment: The issue is that your project is running a version below 14 when building the app in Vercel. Have you tried bumping Node.js to 14.x in your Vercel project settings?

Comment: @juliomalves yep the setting was actually in vercel as you said, if you post this as an answer I'm happy to ✅ it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is that your project in Vercel is setup for Node.js 12 when building the app, which fails due to Playwright requiring Node >=14.

You can increase the Node.js version in your Vercel project under the **Node.js Version** section on the General page of the **Project Settings**.

See [Node.js Version](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/how-do-i-return-an-error/node-js-version) in Vercel for more details.